# What will be value of path attribute in spring if it has refrence of object of another class

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am a newbie in spring mvc framework - 
I am stuck with a problem which is something like that -

There are classess

```
class User{
private String name;
private City city;
//getters setters
}

class Country{
private int id;
private String name;
//getters setters
}

class State{
private int id;
private String name;
private Country country;
//getters setters
}

class city{
private int id;
private String name;
private State state;
State state;
//getters setters
}
```

I have a form like that

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
<form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
<form:input path="name"/>

<form:label path="city.state.country">Country</form:label>  //Getting error here
<form:select path="city.state.country"></form:select>
<form:label path="city.state"></form:label>
<form:select path="city.state"></form:select>
<form:label path="city"></form:label>
<form:select path="city"></form:select>
</formform>
```

**Error**
`org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'city.state' of bean class [org.opentutor.beans.User]: Bean property 'city.state' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:`

Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Basically I am confused how to set users country, state and city values.

Comment: Could you post the getter of `city.state`?

Comment: hi mabbas here is the getter method

public State getState() {
        return this.state;
}

Comment: Do you also have `User#getCity()`, exactly like that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes i have getCity in User class but its return type is int like public int getCity() as the User bean is a hibernate POJO

Comment: @Ravi That doesn't make any sense to me. Why don't you return the `City` field you have?

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis you are right that was the problem i changed return type as City and problem got resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't enough for your classes to have `getX` methods. They need to actually return objects that make sense. For example, `getCity()` needs to return a `City` object, so that the path `city.state.country` can be resolved as `user.getCity().getState().getCountry()`. It can't do that if you have a `getCity()` method that returns an `int`.

Comment: Hey @Sotirios one more help
In the country select field in option i am encrypting the id of country so its in string format when i am submitting the form its giving me error
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property city.state.country.id; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "163044674717253080442465158201917951236198367248"

I know the error is because country has id property of type integer and this encrypted string value can not parsed as integer. So what is the way to convert it before sending

Answer (score 0):

In `User` you need a `getCity()` method. In `City` you need a `getState()` method, in `State` you need a `getCountry()` method. You also need to preinitialize the different objects. If one of the elements in the path resolves to `null` it will not work (as there is nothing to bind to).

Basically you need an empty, non-null, object for each of the elements in the path. Depending on the Spring version you use this is automatically handled for you (in older versions you needed to manually initialize the whole path).